# How to solve the Conversion Tag Error : net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I'm using Google Tag Manager to set a Google Ads conversion tag in my website. When I was debugging using the Tag Assistant window from GTM, my conversion tag was fired successful. When I opened the Tag Assistant Legacy extension from Chrome, I found two error messages related to the "Google Ads Conversion Tracking" tag:

- "An error occured while the tag was fired: net::ERR_ABORTED"
- "Error while sending request: net::ERR_ABORTED"

How can I solve this error messages?

Other tags such as "Google Tag Manager", "Global Site Tag (gtag.js)" or "Remarketing Tag" had no errors.

My site is https://mardemor.com.br

Thanks